# How to mock or assert whether window.alert has fired in React & Jest with typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am using jest tests to test my React project written in #typescript created with Create React App. I'm using `react-testing-library`. I have a form component which shows an `alert` if the form is submitted empty. I wanted to test this feature (maybe) by spying/mocking the `window.alert` but it doesn't work.

I tried using `jest.fn()` as suggested in many SO answers but that's not working too.

```
window.alert = jest.fn();
expect(window.alert).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
```

Here's how I implemented it: Form.tsx

```
async handleSubmit(event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) {
   // check for errors
    if (errors) {
        window.alert('Some Error occurred');
        return;
    }
}
```

Here's how I built the React+Jest+react-testing-library test: Form.test.tsx

```
it('alerts on submit click', async () => {
  const alertMock = jest.spyOn(window,'alert'); 
  const { getByText, getByTestId } = render(<Form />)
  fireEvent.click(getByText('Submit'))
  expect(alertMock).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
})
```

Comment: I see `handleSubmit` is async. Are you doing any `await` before calling `alert`?

Comment: Yes, I call await `await saveImagetoStorage()` which saves an image to FirebaseStorage, as well as call `await activityObject.createActivity();` which saves a document to Firebase-Firestore. Is that an issue?

Comment: Oh, do I need to [use](https://www.leighhalliday.com/async-axios-react-testing-library) `await waitForElement(() => getByText(/_______/i));` before expecting `alertMock`?

Answer (score 14):

I think you might need to tweak your test ever so slightly by adding `.mockImplementation()` to your `spyOn` like so:

```
it('alerts on submit click', async () => {
  const alertMock = jest.spyOn(window,'alert').mockImplementation(); 
  const { getByText, getByTestId } = render(<Form />)
  fireEvent.click(getByText('Submit'))
  expect(alertMock).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
})
```

Answer (score 5):

You could try to use `global` instead of `window`:

```
global.alert = jest.fn();
expect(global.alert).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
```

Alternatively, try to `Object.assign`

```
const alert = jest.fn()
Object.defineProperty(window, 'alert', alert);
```

Comment: I get the following error on using `global.alert`. `Property 'alert' does not exist on type 'Global'.ts(2339)
`. Still, `npm test` runs, but the expect statement fails.

Comment: What about `Object.assign` on the window object?

Comment: Do you mean like this:
`Object.assign(window.alert,jest.fn());`
And then later checking with: 
`expect(window.alert).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)`
Expect fails here too.