# How to check if alert has been called in Jest testing React using Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, ts-jest, react-typescript

I have a HTML select with some options which when I press a button get submitted to a server. Depending on the response an alert is shown.
The method looks like this:

```js
 const sendOrder = async (json : string) => {
        const request = await fetchUrl("<irrelevant url>", "POST", json);
        if(request.status === 200){
            const order = await request.json();
            alert(`Created Order #${order.data.id}`)
        }else{
            alert("Order failed")      
        }
    }
```

Now I have mocked the server using msw and my test looks something like this:

```js
it('should create an order', async () => {

        render(<ArticleList />);
        render(<ShoppingCart afterSubmit={()=> {}}/>)

        const articlesList = getNullSafeElement('articles');
        await waitFor(() => {
            expect(articlesList.children.length).toBe(2);
        })
        const orderButton = getNullSafeElement('submitBtn');
        const shoppingCart =  document.querySelector('#cart') as HTMLSelectElement; 
        const addressInput = document.querySelector('#address') as HTMLInputElement;

        addressInput.value = "testAddress"
        expect(shoppingCart.options.length).toBe(0);
        fireEvent.click(articlesList.children[0]);
        expect(shoppingCart.children.length).toBe(1);
        fireEvent.click(orderButton);
        
      });
```

I know for sure that this test runs as expected and that the request is definetly beeing sent to the mocked server by `fireEvent.click(orderButton)`.
However, if I now want to do something like this `expect(global.alert).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)`, it does not work.
Now I know that I have to mock the call and I saw some posts on SO about this issue

[Mock or asser whether window.alert has fired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55933105/how-to-mock-or-assert-whether-window-alert-has-fired-in-react-jest-with-typesc)

[Test alert in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61122548/how-to-test-alert-in-react-native-with-jest)

But neither `global.alert = jest.fn()`, nor `jest.spyOn(global, 'alert')` have worked out. Both result in 0 calls.

So my question is: How can I test if `alert()` has been called in my test?

(I am creating a frontend using create-react-app with the typescript template and testing with Jest)

Comment: Did you use `waitFor` when checking if it was called?

Comment: I tried it with `waitFor` and without, in both cases the test fails telling me :
`expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCallesTimes(expected)
Expected number of calls: 1
Received number of calls: 0`

Answer (score 0):

Might be a late but I ran into same problem.

I resolved it by using await ahead of the fireEvent click. In your case,

```js
it('should create an order', async () => {
    global.alert = jest.fn();

    render(<ArticleList />);
    render(<ShoppingCart afterSubmit={()=> {}}/>)

    const articlesList = getNullSafeElement('articles');
    await waitFor(() => {
        expect(articlesList.children.length).toBe(2);
    })
    const orderButton = getNullSafeElement('submitBtn');
    const shoppingCart =  document.querySelector('#cart') as HTMLSelectElement; 
    const addressInput = document.querySelector('#address') as HTMLInputElement;

    addressInput.value = "testAddress"
    expect(shoppingCart.options.length).toBe(0);
    fireEvent.click(articlesList.children[0]);
    expect(shoppingCart.children.length).toBe(1);
    await fireEvent.click(orderButton);
    expect(global.alert).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
```